# How to create independent/fixed inset maps with leaflet?

Tags: r, leaflet-r

I am trying to create a `leaflet` map of the USA focusing on the contiguous 48 states and then add two inset maps of Alaska and Hawaii on the side. The problem is that `addMiniMap()` option creates an interactive inset mini map that just shows the location of the zoom window of the main map. Rather than this, I want to have inset maps with **fixed** position and zoom on Alaska and Hawaii, while the main map remains interactive.

Comment: `leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addMiniMap(centerFixed=c(63, -150),zoomLevelFixed=2)` gives me an Alaska-focused mini map but I can't see how to add another one based on Hawaii. Multiple `addMiniMap` functions don't have any effect (even with different `position` parameters)

Comment: I think that would be a different question.

Comment: The question asks for two inset maps (Alaska and Hawaii). Want to close it as "too broad" then?

Comment: @Spacedman This works quite well, but with two issues, one being that the inset map doesn't reflect the data from the main map (though this would be a different question), but more importantly, is that indeed I would want two/multiple fixed inset maps at the same time. Perhaps `addMiniMap` isn't a way to go here. Thank you for help all the same!

Comment: Best you can do is use a shapefile/spatial object where AK and HA are not in the right place geographically. But underlying tiles will be wrong. See https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/172 - or resort to hand-crafted Javascript and multiple map items on an HTML page.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks, sounds good! I will probably go about custom JS route you suggested and will post my solution if/when I get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `centerFixed` and `zoomLevelFixed`:

> #### `centerFixed`
>
> Applies a fixed position to the minimap regardless of the main map's view / position. Prevents panning the minimap, but does allow zooming (both in the minimap and the main map). If the minimap is zoomed, it will always zoom around the centerFixed point. You can pass in a LatLng-equivalent object. Defaults to false.
>
> #### `zoomLevelFixed`
>
> Overrides the offset to apply a fixed zoom level to the minimap regardless of the main map zoom. Set it to any valid zoom level, if unset zoomLevelOffset is used instead.

[Source](https://rdrr.io/cran/leaflet/man/addMiniMap.html)